# Summation to the square of n -n

Tags: summation

Does anyone know the correct way to write a summation starting with

(n^2)-n subtracting n, ending at n ...

I'm trying to find out if it's legitimate to put (n^2)-n as the lower limit, or to put n as the lower then go to (n^2)-n as the upper adding n as oppose to subtracting it.

Sample sequences: 4+8+12 = 24

ie. take 4 and add 4 2(4-2)times

5+10+15+20 = 50 ... So it's bound by the square of itself minus itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard summation notation only works for a step size of 1, but you can write

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(kn) $$

Then the first term will be $f(1n)=f(n)$ and the last term will be $f((n-1)n)=f(n^2-n)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm slightly confused by there seeming to be two 'rules' for the upper part, one seems to apply to simple summation, where the upper denotes the end point, and a second rule for more complex where it denotes 'the number of times' the process is applied. Here in your example you appear to have used the second. Could you help clarify? Thank you

Comment: @Martin: No, the limits always denote the endpoints. In this example we start with $k=1$, so at the beginning we have $kn=1n=n$, and we end with $k=n-1$, so at the end we have $kn=(n-1)n=n^2-n$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm slowly grasping it

Comment: Thanks Henning, I think I will take about two days to grasp the entirety of what you have done, but I can see it's overcome the self-referential aspect. Very good.

Comment: yes, by increasing k every time.

Comment: @mdave16: No, that is not a good example of an indexed sum. It doesn't match the _usual_ definition of an indexed sum (namely the limit that can be approached by summing over ever larger _finite_ subsets of the index set), and the summation principles that do yield $-1/12$ for $1+2+3+\cdots$ are not stable under reorderings of the series, so there saying $\sum_{i\in \mathbb N}$ rather than $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$ loses _essential_ information.

Comment: Of course, I need absolute convergence for it, I just couldn't think of any at the time and just hurriedly put it down, I'll delete and correct. Thank you!

Comment: More generally, you can even do something like $$\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} f(i),$$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is some index set previously defined (so long as the sum is absolutely convergent, in particular, you can reorder the terms in the sum to get the value. For example $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} 1/i^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Thanks to @HenningMakholm for correcting me.